# AX 2012 business connector use

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, proxy

I am using Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012, and want to logon to AX environment outside (using proxy account).

## What I do is:

```
using MIL = Microsoft.Dynamics.AX.ManagedInterop;
...
public static MIL.Session axSession = null;
if (MIL.Session.Current == null
                        || !MIL.Session.Current.isLoggedOn())
                            try
                            {
                                // Login to Microsoft Dynamics Ax.
                                axSession = new MIL.Session();
                                axSession.Logon(null, null, null, null);
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred in object creation or Axapta logon: {0}", e.Message);
                                return null;
                            }
```

... but instead of axSession.Logon(null, null, null, null); I want to do:
axSession.Logon("35", "en-us", "AXDEV", null) where ever: company = 35, language = 'en-us' and environment = 'axdev'.

For some reason the above doesn't do the login (with null value for all of the parameters - login is fine, but it take the default values from client configuration and proxy default company).

What may be wrong on the syntax axSession.Logon("35", "en-us", "AXDEV", null).
I get "AXDEV" as explained on: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsession.aosname.aspx

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you get exception or what ? In case of exception, share the exception details please